# Can I declare a Pistolero's Up Close and Deadly use after hitting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, gunslinger

The [Pistolero](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger/archetypes/paizo-gunslinger-archetypes/pistolero/) deed reads as:

> **Up Close and Deadly (Ex)** At 1st level, when the pistolero hits a target with a one-handed firearm that is not making a scatter shot, she can spend 1 grit point to deal 1d6 points of extra damage on a hit. If she misses with the attack, she grazes the target, dealing half the extra damage anyway. This is precision damage and is not multiplied if the attack is a critical hit. This precision damage increases to 2d6 at 5th level, to 3d6 at 10th level, to 4d6 at 15th level, and to 5d6 at 20th level.

So if I understand this RAW I don't have to declare until after I've hit.

**Is that correct?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in fact in the errata Paizo removed a sentence that had originally been in the ability that said "She must choose to spend the grit point before she makes the attack roll."

This leaves the ability slightly unclear because of the damage-on-a-miss effect; the consensus is you can spend grit after the attack to get the extra damage on a hit or half on a miss.

Note that errata also adds the sentence "The cost of using this deed cannot be reduced with the Signature Deed feat, the true grit class feature, or any
similar effect."